# SQL Server 2008 FTS problem, best alternative

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, lucene.net

I develop news search engine with C# and SQL Server 2008
i using SQL Full text search for search and it's ok until some week ago.

currently i have more than 100 million record,  that daily added about 1 million article.
but i see sometimes when user search, one of 8 CPU become 100% and take some minutes.
after repopulate catalog, it's ok for some days, What's really problem ?

Note: I set automatic track changes and schedule it for incremental population when CPU become Idle

Also I need to know what's best alternative ?

- Lucene.Net
- Xapian
- Sphinx
- Solar
- Or any other best solution ?

Could you please help me ?

Comment: I have heard good things using lucene with large amounts of data.

Comment: Hamid, what sort of queries are being run? What is actually happening on the server when the CPU spikes ? You might want to take a look at this technet article (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345185.aspx) Troubleshooting: Slow Full-Text Indexing Performance Due to Filtering Process

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you go over this white paper: [SQL Server 2005 Full-Text Queries on Large Catalogs: Lessons Learned](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917695.aspx), which explains some techniques used by the SQL CAT (Customer Advisory Team) to manage a 420Gb database with a FT catalog of 10Gb.

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you are adding 1 million articles per day, SQL needs to merge the indexes, which would cause a spike for a while until the indexes are merged.

This sounds like normal behaviour and you will experience this type of resource contention with the scale you are pushing with any alternative full-text indexing engine.